# Delay in starting Database services on Server 2012 R2

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2012-r2, service, sqlanywhere

We have found in the past couple of days (unknown when this first appeared) that services for MYSQL and SQLAnywhere 16 are taking 20 minutes to start when a windows 2012 R2 server is rebooted.  After this time they run without any issues.  We have not been able to identify a cause for this.  Any thoughts on what we can look at to speed the services start-up?

We have tried to run quick start-up to see what processes were taking too long to start up but everything else seemed to run in a timely manner.  We when tried to run Proc Mon on the server but this was not able to run at all for an unknown reason (we are still working on this part).

We have disabled both the SQLAnywhere and MYSQL services in various combinations to see if they are affecting each other but they are not as the problem persists when only one of the two applications is running.

The SQLAnywhere DB will start up in next to no time when running with DBSRV16 when triggered manually but the service will not start without the long delay.

Comment: Maybe a network problem as it is verifying whether its server name already exists in the network. The parameter is something like DoBroadcast...